# Shell variable value in pre-defined range

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want a variable whose value should be in already defined range.

for e.g.

variable DAY=$1

should only get values Mon,Tue,Wed,Thus,Fri,Sat,Sun.

if user enter something else, it will not accept it.

I know i can do this by defining array or normally a variable storing all the days and then check variable DAY in a "for or while" loop.

But i want the simplest way without loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the extended glob support to match exactly one of a list of choices.

```
range="Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri"
read day
if [[ $day = @($range) ]]; then
    echo "$day is valid"
else
    echo "$day is not valid"
fi
```

Comment: This is the only safe answer. Besides, it's the clearest and shortest. Thanks chepner for making such good answers!

Comment: To my surprise, `shopt -s extglob` wasn't actually necessary, even in 3.2. The release notes for 4.1 indicate that `extglob` is temporarily turned on inside `[[ ... ]]` "for compatibility", which seems to hint that such patterns are always extended patterns, even if not explicitly documented as such. (Which makes some sense; you don't need POSIX pattern compatibility inside a non-POSIX construct, and the patterns are matching strings, not path names.)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! You may revert my edit (sorry about this).

Comment: OK, it *is* documented. I never read the man page for 3.2 carefully enough: "When the == and != operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below under Pattern  Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled."

Answer (score 1):

Without using a loop you can do something like this:

```
EOL=$'\n'
arr=(Mon Tue Wed Thus Fri Sat Sun)
read -p 'Enter day value: ' day
Tue

[[ $(printf "$EOL%s$EOL" "${arr[@]}") == *"$EOL$day$EOL"* ]] &&
   echo "in range" || echo "not in range"
in range

read -p 'Enter day value: ' day
ue We
[[ $(printf "$EOL%s$EOL" "${arr[@]}") == *"$EOL$day$EOL"* ]] &&
   echo "in range" || echo "not in range"
not in range
```

Comment: Thanks, seems working but what for the else condition. i mean when entered value is not in range and i want to do something for that case.

Comment: i guess i can use [[ -z $day ]] && echo "in range" || echo "not in range".
But do you have anything better then this, plz suggest.

Comment: `[[ -z $day ]]` will only check length of string to be zero, it won't check whether `$day` exists in array `$arr`

Comment: This allows odd inputs like "ue We" to be accepted.

Comment: @chepner: That's a good point, I corrected it now, pls check.

Comment: Fundamentally, it still accepts a superset of the intended 3-letter day abbreviations, but at least now it's unlikely the user will type one of the false positives. The problem is you are essentially allowing the user to specify the test condition, not the value to test.

Comment: Hmm using `$'\n'` will be better separator as entering newline isn't possible via `read` variable.

Comment: @AmitKumar: Did you find any problem with updated code?

Comment: no extremely not but the other one is much simple for me. 
Your answer works too. And thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

To expand slightly on anubhava's answer:

```
arr=(Mon Tue Wed Thus Fri Sat Sun)
read -p 'Enter day value: ' day
case "${arr[@]}" in *"$day"*) echo "in range";; esac
```

Basically, this is building an array, turning it into a string, and doing a pattern match on it.

In the context of a `case` expression, there's no difference between `"${arr[@]}"` and `"${arr[*]}"`; I personally would stick with `*`, which makes it clearer that you're building one big string instead of a list of separate ones.

With this specific set of values, you don't have to worry about substring overlap, but the above check is still overly forgiving.  For instance, if you enter `u`, it will be considered "in range".  That may not be what you want.

A more exact test would be something like this:

```
case "${arr[*]}" in
   "$day "*|*" $day "*|*" $day") echo "in range";;
    *) echo "not in range";;
esac
```

This still permits the user to enter multiple days as "Mon Tue" or similar; an easy way to fix that in this particular case is to change the `read` line from `read day` to `read day _`.

The `"$day "*` pattern will match at the beginning of the array (so if they enter `Mon` in this case).  The `*" $day"` pattern will match at the end of the array (`Fri`), and the `*" $day "*` pattern will match the rest.  Nothing else but an exact day string will match.

Also, here you can see how to handle the `else` case - a pattern of `*` matches anything that hasn't already matched something else, so that's the equivalent of `else` in a `case`.

Comment: Fails if user enters `Mon Tue`.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for an array.

```
read -r day
case ' Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun ' in
  *" $day "*)
    echo "in range";;
  *) echo "not in range";;
esac
```

Notice the spaces around the string expressions.

If you need to be strict, you should reject "Tue Wed" which this doesn't do. It would require a second `case` wrapper, which is clunky but not completely unwieldy.